# Динамическое заполнение Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

На форме имеется объект Spinner - выпадающий список. Элементы которые он отображает берутся из массива. Как организовать ввод текста в Spinner, чтобы при вводе отображаемые элементы фильтровались, в зависимости от введенного текста?

Код спинера в разметке:

```
 <Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Код формы:

```
String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.name_and_zakaz);

    // Получаем экземпляр элемента Spinner
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Настраиваем адаптер
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Вызываем адаптер
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Складывается впечатление, что вы хотите навелосипедить свой [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), 
[Пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/243853/)

Comment: Понял, благодарю, просто думал, что в Android Studio нет такого элемента